# Can I/Should I add authentication providers at runtime using Servicestack

Tags: security, authentication, servicestack

I have a multi-tenant, microservice application using ServiceStack for everything but the front end in which we have several types of clients, mostly cordova based. We have a request from different clients using different directories in Azure to be able to Authenticate with their in house credentials...makes sense.
Touched base with [@jfoshee](https://github.com/jfoshee), he has done all of the heavy lifting for the aad part...thanks for your contribution. Is it possible to register/remove auth providers at runtime so that I can have an instance per ad tenant running on the auth server configured appropriately with necessary info...is this even a good idea in regards to security?

Answer (score 1):

No, Auth Providers need to be initialized once in `AppHost.Configure()` and remain immutable thereafter. Depending on your requirements you may want to create a multi-tenant-aware Custom AuthProvider that dynamically authenticates users based on their configuration.